# Do AVDs (Android Virtual Devices) write logs? If so where?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

About 3 days ago, after doing a bunch of AVD updates, SDK updates, Eclipse updates, Windows updates, doing end of year backups.... all **new** AVDs I create using the AVD manager seem to crash while loading. Windows pops up a box with the following message.

- Emulator-arm.exe has stopped working
- A problem caused the program to stop working correctly;
- Windows will closed the program and notify you if a solution is available [Close Program]

AVDs created more then a week ago still seem to be working fine. Dose the AVD write logs I can examine to try and figure out what happened (I'm a curious kind of guy, and like to figure out what happened, rather then just uninstall/reinstall the AVD and hope for the best.)?
My questions are:

1 - Do ADVs and/or the ADV manager write logs when they have problems?

2 - Where do I find any of these logs? / How should I read them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the emulator from within a terminal to get all the output ( including errors ).

Run "emulator.exe -help" to get the complete list of possible arguments.

Comment: Hi Robert :
Ran emulator as C:\Andriod\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools>emulator.exe -avd joe_04 -verbose
Crashed as before with following info in log 
-
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
-
Searched SO, found this might be caused by allocating too much memory. Reduced memory allocation to 512 Meg.
Restarting AVD with lower memory got me past the original problem, but the AVD never fully activated.
Will post new problem tomorrow - Thanks